# How can I track users in Firebase Analytics?

Tags: firebase, tracking, firebase-analytics

I want to track users separately or find out which users are doing an specific event
It will be terrible if I do this with creating custom audience for based on userId or some user property.
I'm looking for a efficient way for find my top clients and send them push notification or save their email.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Firebase analytics is built so that you cannot track specific users with custom audiences (you are limited on the amount of custom audineces).

What you want to do is find a way to segment your 'best' into an audience. You could maybe look at making a [funnel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806933/firebase-analytics-setting-up-user-flow-tracking).

Comment: Thanks. But I think that "Funnel" can't fit to my issue. I found "user explorer" in Google analytics that shows user's sessions and etc. Isn't any alternative in Firebase?

Comment: I am not too familiar with Firebase Analytics, so you would have to look in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/)